# Filter a number of divs with data-attribute from external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a number of links that filters a number of divs depending on data-attribute.

Now I would like to separate the links and the resulting divs to separate pages. For example: I've got page X with links and page Y with resulting divs. When I click a link on page X, I get directed to page Y and the correct div is shown. How would I do that in the best way? Is it possible to do this using the data-attributes?

js

```
var target;

$('.filter_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (target != $(this).attr('data-related')) {
        $('.blurb-content').removeClass('fade-in-bottom').addClass('blurb--hidden');
        var $blurbsToShow = $('.cat_' + $(this).attr('data-related'));
        $blurbsToShow.each(function(i) {
        var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $self.removeClass('blurb--hidden').addClass('fade-in-bottom');
            }, 500 * i);
        });
        target = $(this).attr('data-related');

    } else {
        target = '';

        $('.blurb-content').removeClass('blurb--hidden').removeClass('fade-in-bottom');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdornell/kha70yev/)

Comment: If you get redirected to pageY, this page needs to know which divs to show. The easiest way I can think of is adding something to the URL (either a query string parameter, or a hash), and read it once on the new page. Other ways to do it would be to store the value in cookies, localStorage, or sessionStorage, but I would recommend just using the URL to pass that information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is that the filtering that I've got now should still work on page Y so I guess I need to figger out how to show the right divs after the redirect (preferably without having to rewrite too much of my code). I manage to solve the redirect issue but I'm not sure how to fix so that it not shows all the divs after the redirect.